# Index method for very few updates and many inserts

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, gist-index, gin-index

I am using Postgresql 9.1 with *pg_trgm* extension. I need to create an index on a text-based field. I do not need full-text searches, I use `ILIKE` queries to make my searches.

I will use `pg_trgm` but do not have much experience with `gin` and `gist` indexes. I will have many `INSERT` statements (~15000 daily) and very few `UPDATE` statements (may be 1 or 2 in a week).

What will be the index update overhead for a `gin` index on a such table? Or is `gist` more suitable?

Comment: An important missing detail is the frequency of index searches, which has to be weighed against the cost of index maintenance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual for the pg_trgm module has some advice for your question [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#AEN143969):

> As a rule of thumb, a GIN index is faster to search than a GiST index,
>   but slower to build or update; so GIN is better suited for static data
>   and GiST for often-updated data.

The [**`FASTUPDATE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/gin-implementation.html#GIN-FAST-UPDATE) feature of GIN indexes (introduced in Postgres 8.4, ON by default) should be interesting for you. INSERTs (and UPDATEs) are stored in a pending list and integrated into the index in later bulk operations by `VACUUM`. Makes those operations a lot faster, since direct GIN maintenance tends to be expensive, especially for columns with many indexable elements, i.e. many words in your case.

[More basic advice on GIN vs GiST in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/gin-tips.html)
In particular, if your rows are big and you insert in bulks, you may want to raise the [`work_mem` setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM).

For very big loads (large parts of the table), it might pay to drop the index and recreate it afterwards.
Although, 15k rows spread out over a day, shouldn't be a problem at all.

Finally, there is a [**whole chapter on performance of GIN and GiST**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-indexes.html) in the Full Text Search section. Applies generally. Read this.

The gist of it (no pun intended): GIN is considerably bigger and more expensive to maintain, but faster for most lookups ([special exceptions apply for pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#AEN143969)). Since the addition of `FASTUPDATE` writes are only moderately more expensive.